# Right time format of using timeMax retrieving Google Calendar Events in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, calendar, google-calendar-api

I was trying to retrieve Google calendar events using PHP for some analysing purposes. I used `singleEvents= True` settings to expand recurring events as single instances. In order to avoid retrieving unlimited recurring events, I tried to set the event start upper bound to 2015-06-01.

Here is the code I was using:

```
$eventList = $cal->events->listEvents($tempCal["id"], array(maxResults   =>5000,singleEvents => True,timeMax => '2015-06-01T00:00:00-04:00'));
```

But it seems the timeMax parameter does not work.

I tried other time format '2015-06-01T00:00:00Z' and it does not work either.

However, I tried the same string using web browser and it retrieved all events before 2015-06-01 using https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

What was wrong with my timeMax format?

Answer (score 1):

The Solution who worked for me (ordering and time-bounds):

```
/* retrieve events for today */
$start = date(DateTime::ATOM, mktime(0,0,0,date('m'), date('d'), date('Y')));
$end = date(DateTime::ATOM, mktime(23,59,59,date('m'), date('d'), date('Y')));

$eventOptions = array("orderBy"=>"startTime",
                      "singleEvents"=>true,
                      "timeMin"=>$start,
                      "timeMax"=>$end);
$events = $service->events->listEvents($calendar_id, $eventOptions);
```